# Export to Excel button not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

My export to excel button keep not showing even after i used those code above. I don't have any idea with what's happening with those code. Someone with greater experience please help me. I got my reference from https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

```
        <table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'excel'
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's the console output:

[image]

Comment: 1) Do we really need to see all of your rows in your example? Keep it to the minimum! 2) Open your browser's developer console, run your code, and let us if you have any console errors. 3) Add those to your question.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I'm sorry sir, it's my first time.. I've updated my question
btw thanks for your tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to you use the export plugin you also need to include the following scripts:

`//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js`
`https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js`
`https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js`
`//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.flash.min.js`
`//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js`
`//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/pdfmake.min.js`
`//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/vfs_fonts.js`
`//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.html5.min.js`
`//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.print.min.js`

This is detailed in the link you provided. View the source of that page to see how they've included them.

Comment: actually i've done that.. I've included those scripts.. I put those between the end of my table and that script tag.. Is it the wrong place?

Comment: I think you need to check the order of your scripts, table and other tags. Compare this to the linked version. Also, you may need to be running on a web server, are you?

Comment: Thanks for all your help then sir.. I'll try to recheck them again then..